# Pass information from popup to main window on Oracle ADF

Tags: java, oracle, popup, oracle-adf

I have a popup that show a table with data, I am able to select a row, and by pressing a OK button I can retrieve the idNo of the selected row in the table.

What I want to do is to pass this idNo to the window that is calling the popup and update a outputText that is on this window.

Can some one help me?

Code for the button:

newBean Class for the button:

```
 public String b1_action() {
        // Add event code here...

        System.out.println("Select One Button has been Clicked");

            // Get bindings associated with the current scope, then access the one that we have assigned to our table - e.g. OpenSupportItemsIterator
            DCBindingContainer bindings =
                (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
            DCIteratorBinding dcItteratorBindings =
                bindings.findIteratorBinding("NameView1_1Iterator");

            // Get an object representing the table and what may be selected within it
            ViewObject voTableData = dcItteratorBindings.getViewObject();

            // Get selected row
            Row rowSelected = voTableData.getCurrentRow();

            // Display attriebute of row in console output - would generally be bound to a UI component like a Label and or used to call another proces
            System.out.println(rowSelected.getAttribute("IdNo"));

            setOutputText("" + rowSelected.getAttribute("IdNo") + "");
            closePopup("p1");

        return null;
    }
```

I want that my function: `setOutputText()` which is not implemented yet to be able to update my outputText on the main Window.

Thanks
Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Put the "IdNo" in view or page flow scope depending on how you want to keep the value.

```
//view scope
AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewScope().put("IdNo", value);

//or page flow scope
AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPageFlowScope.put("IdNo", value);
```

In the window bean, write a listener for the popup dialog:

```
public void dialogCloseListener(DialogEvent dialogEvent) {
    if (dialogEvent.getOutcome().equals(DialogEvent.Outcome.ok)) {
        String idNo = AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewScope().get("IdNo");
        //now you have the idNo, do whatever you want

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the returnListener inside the button or link that is invoking the popup like in [this article](http://www.jobinesh.com/2010/08/refresh-parent-view-when-in-line-popup.html)